# ¿Cómo poner imágenes en div a lado en html?

Tags: html, css

He intentado de todo pero siempre me queda así:

```
----------
l imagen1 l
---------- 
texto img1

----------
l imagen2 l
----------
texto img2
```

En cambio lo que quiero es esto (centrado) con dos o más imágenes y el texto sobre las imágenes en un `background-image`:

```
---------- ----------
l imagen1 l l imagen2 
---------- ----------
```

No sé si me explico bien, pero la cuestión es ¿cómo lo hago?

He intentado:

```css
.imga1 {
  background-image: url(http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/763617/images/img-left.png?t=1466090614807);
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <center>
    <div class="imga1"></div>
    <div class="imga1"></div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Debes mostrar el código que has intentado, imagino que solo es cuestión de añadir la propiedad float:left o display:inline-block a los div pero es importante que muestres tu estructura

Comment: Como puedes comprobar ejecutando el ejemplo de tu propio código sí que se colocan una a continuación de la otra.

Comment: Se colocan una al lado de la otra, pero las quiere centradas. Para ello tan sólo tendría que **quitar el `float:left` y poner el `display:inline-block`** como le sugiere Camilo Vasquez

Comment: Cierto. No lo había leído bien

Answer (score 2):

Para acomodar tus elementos horizontalmente y que a su vez queden centrados en relación a su contenedor simplemente debes aplicarle la propiedad `display: inline-block` y al contenedor aplicarle `text-align: center` y listo.

```css
#contenedor{
  text-align: center;
}

.imga1 {
  background-image: url(http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/763617/images/img-left.png?t=1466090614807);
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <center>
    <div class="imga1"></div>
    <div class="imga1"></div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#contenedor
  .img
  .texto

#contenedor {
  position: relative;
}
.img {
  height: 100px;
}
.texto {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta pueda ser correcta, para que sea mas útil deberías explicar un poco mas porqué soluciona el problema del OP.

Comment: Debes responder agregando una explicación a tu código por favor revisa [answer].